# angluar-cli build: An unhandled exception occurred: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to build an angular project using the following command:

ng build --configuration=production and I'm getting the following error:

```
70% building 4/4 modules 0 activeAn unhandled exception occurred: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
See "/private/var/folders/3q/rg85j7dj5dz5g37jk56731f40000gr/T/ng-p04YBZ/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

while ng build works as expected.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "single-spa": "^5.8.0",
    "single-spa-angular": "^4.3.0",
    "systemjs-webpack-interop": "~2.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^3.4.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you resolve this issue

1. Go to angular.json
2. Under "configurations", find "production"
3. set "**extractCss**" to **false**, it will currently be true

Hope this helped!